# How to detect click outside React APPLICATION?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want a functional React component to close whenever the user clicks outside the application as well as outside the component within the application.

I've worked out how to close the component so long as the user clicks inside the containing application, but it still ignores clicks in an entirely different Windows application.

I want to emulate the behavior of the "Avatar" button at the top right of a Google Maps window. The button opens a modal dialog that is dismissed when the user clicks anywhere outside the dialog.

My current code has a `useEffect` hook that calls `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` on the current `document`:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleClickOutside = (event) => {
      if (wrapperRef.current && !wrapperRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
        onCloseButtonClick(event)
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener("click", handleClickOutside, true);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("click", handleClickOutside, true);
    };
  }, [onCloseButtonClick]);
```

I had hoped the solution was as simple as attaching `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` on `window` instead of `document`, but it doesn't work.

How can I clear the `visible` property of the component when the user clicks outside the containing application?

Thanks in advance for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to also listen to `onblur` on the window. That can call the `onCloseButtonClick` straight away as theres no element attached to those events.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const handleClickOutside = (event) => {
      if (wrapperRef.current && !wrapperRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
        onCloseButtonClick(event)
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener("click", handleClickOutside, true);
    window.addEventListener("blur", onCloseButtonClick, true);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("click", handleClickOutside, true);
      window.removeEventListener("blur", onCloseButtonClick, true);
    };
  }, [onCloseButtonClick]);
```

Comment: If I do that, won't it hide the component when the mouse leaves the window?

I want it to wait until the user clicks outside the window. In the old days of writing actual desktop apps, I would use the `onBlur` to capture the cursor and then catch (and propagate) an `onClick` after that. If the user moves the cursor outside and then back inside (with no intervening click), then I want the element to stay visible.

Comment: No, as the blur event only triggers on window if the user causes the window to lose focus, which requires either clicking on another window or minimizing. Moving the mouse out of the window by itself will not cause it. So this should do exactly what you need.

Comment: BTW you can feel free to ignore this if im wrong :D, but what you are trying to do is usually (not always) frowned upon from UX perspective. Their are different expectations about web vs desktop apps. When a user leaves the window and comes back, you are usually expecting it to be in the exact same state. But I dont know enough about the use case. If you really want it, this should work.

Comment: The reasoning is the user generally sees an active click outside of an element as an explicit instruction to close whatevers in the foreground -- so thats fine. But UX wise, when a user switches window this is not the same user intent, it means "im going to come back to this later". Coming back to find it gone, depending on use case, may be more annoying than useful. Usually, most webapps dont do this. Anyway -- im veering into my UX skills on a coding forum now :D

Comment: I appreciate and share your UIX concerns. I'm emulating the behavior of Google web apps, and I make the perhaps rash assumption that users will expect my app to behave the same way.

Your answer produces precisely the desired behavior and I very much appreciate it!